# MySQL the world database sql file has syntax error when inserting data

Tags: mysql, sql

I download The world database from http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/world.sql.gz
However when I pasted all the content in the sql file into phpMyAdmin to create the tables, error shows:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'The Valley','AIA','?,595)' at line 1
```

Don't know why this could be a syntax error

```
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (60,'Namibe','AGO','Namibe',118200);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (61,'South Hill','AIA','?,961);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (62,'The Valley','AIA','?,595);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (63,'Saint John磗','ATG','St John',24000);
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (64,'Dubai','ARE','Dubai',669181);
```

Anyone met this issue before?

Comment: I imported the same dump as you suggested, and I don't faces any issues.

Comment: really? What tool do you use? I use Notepad++ to open the sql file, and then paste the content into phpMyAdmin

Comment: @user3269623 can you check my answer

Comment: phpMyAdmin itself provide the functionality to `import/export` dump you don't need to open the sql file and then paste the content in phpmyadmin. What if the file is too large you can't even open a huge file in notepad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this zip file for dump world database

http://gyankosh.siplstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/worlddump-1.sql_.zip

Comment: Thanks, this one works great! The original file just contains some error.

Answer (score 0):

check the single quotes on the question mark try '?' instead of '?

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (61,'South Hill','AIA','?,961);
```

Here question mark has been treated as string. You should wrap the question mark with single quote. Try this :

```
INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (61,'South Hill','AIA','?',961);

INSERT INTO `City` VALUES (62,'The Valley','AIA','?',595);
```

Comment: Yes this should not actually. But we are human. :) And if it is working then mark it complete. And even you can post this issue to Mysql form.

Answer (score 0):

put quote for '?'

```
INSERT INTO City VALUES (61,'South Hill','AIA','?',961)
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16db9/2)

Answer (score 0):

From your comment I am giving my answer ,I imported the same dump as you suggested, and I don't faces any issues.

`phpMyAdmin` itself provide the functionality to `import/export` dump you don't need to open the sql file and then paste the content in phpmyadmin. What if the file is too large you can't even open a huge file in notepad

Please have a look at http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/import-and-export-databases-using-phpmyadmin/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I pasted the content because there is no CREATE DATABASE statement in the sql file, so I wrote one in phpmyadmin first, and then just pasted the sql file content in.